# Wiki/CMS with synchronization?

Tags: high-availability, disaster-recovery, wiki, cms

We're looking into putting up a wiki or CMS for internal use by our IT department.  One of the big things we want to use it for is disaster recovery procedures.

Given that a disaster, such as a power or network outage, might render the wiki inaccessible, it seems sensible to to host the wiki in two places so that if one is inaccessible, we can fall back to the other.

Are there any wikis or CMSes that synchronize (or an alternate way to achieve a similar end)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have tons of entries per minutes in your wiki, You can also achieve synchronization by using NoSql db [CouchDB](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication) or [Tokyo](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) as a backend. There is also [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/ReplicationHowto). They are replication-friendly.

An experimental solution could be also [**TiddlyWiki**](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) on a [**Dropbox**](http://dropbox.com), really decentralized ! (or maybe too crazy but you can test It :) )

About the Wiki and CMS you can use with those backends [Github](http://github.com/) is the place to search.
[really really simple but extendable](http://github.com/langalex/couchdb_example_wiki)
[simple sinatra couchdb wiki](http://github.com/ashri/couchdb-wiki)
Instiki (Rails) could be adapted with [Ohm](http://github.com/soveran/ohm)

You can also consider **sqlite3** asa synchronizable backend since the db It's just a file. Frameworks like Rails and Django support It out of the box.

**MORE**: After some thinking It comes to my mind that of course you can use **git** too, since it's a decentralized thing by nature. If you build your wiki on top of git, You can add hooks to every push to fire synchronization with other cloned repositories of your wiki or just luanch a pull every few minutes. And [here](http://github.com/sandal/git-wiki) yuo have an example of a wiki-over-git.

I've found also [zim](http://zim-wiki.org/screenshots.html) that you could combine, again with git.

Comment: Any idea which wikis would support using those databases as a backend?

Comment: I really get a kick out of the dropbox idea!

Comment: Added more stuff to answer you.

Comment: Added a git solution too.

Answer (score 2):

i use [dokuwiki](http://dokuwiki.org) with file storage. works very well, and rsync as synchronization metod does a trick.

i trust rsync with all my backups, why would i not trust with wiki replication?

plain-text files in which this wiki stores pages are perfectly readable and searchable directly from shell/mc which is another disaster-recovery advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Wikis like [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) don't use database servers, only local files that can be synced easily with i.e. rsync.

Comment: MoinMoin has also synchronization feature, but I haven't used id. http://moinmo.in/HelpOnSynchronisation

Answer (score 1):

If you like minimalistic file based frameworks you can try [werc](http://werc.cat-v.org/). It follows the plan9 philosophy so expect everything to be a file. That way, sinchronization is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/) for this, even if it is not its main goal to be a CMS. It has wiki and tickets, it can sync over network, it is a single executable, it can run in offline mode it has history of changes (since it is a distributed version control tool).

Answer (score 0):

[ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu) also supports file-based storage, however I would advise you not to rely on home-brew replication strategies (like rsync). I would just opt for a database server that supports replication and failover clustering (like SQL Server).

Comment: rsync is a weird replication strategy? Care to explain?

Comment: ScrewTurn is an ASP.NET application.  I suspect that on Windows, using rsync is a little bit unusual.

Comment: @SwenW rsync is "weird" in a sense that it might not replicate all the data in a way that makes sense. What if the application modifies the data while you're replicating? You'd end up with a broken replica. That's why I suggested to use SQL Server (or any other more robust system that supports hot replication).